# Could someone help me understand how to use the discrete.histogram() function in the arm package?

Tags: r, arm, histogram

I have a question asking me to make a histogram of # survivors across all experiments. I am trying to use the function discrete.histogram() in the arm package but can't figure out what data to input in order to just use my column "Survival".

I found this for the function:

```
discrete.histogram (x, prob, prob2=NULL, prob3=NULL,
xlab="x", xaxs.label=NULL, yaxs.label=NULL, bar.width=NULL,
freq=FALSE, prob.col="blue", prob2.col="red", prob3.col="gray", ...)
```

If I am plotting # of survivors across all experiments, what do I put for x and prob?

This is what I have:

```
discrete.histogram(HeatShock$Survival,xlab = 'Number of Survivors')
```

Thank you.

This is what my data looks like:
[enter image description here][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Th7.png
```

Comment: Is x supposed to be the data and prob is the column I want?

    discrete.histogram (HeatShock,'Survival')

Tried that but got this error:

    Error in discrete.histogram(HeatShock, "Survival") : 
      Length of 'x' must be the same as the length of 'prob'

Comment: I also tried this:

    discrete.histogram (HeatShock$Survival)

It gave me a plot but I'm not sure it was what I am looking for.

Comment: Without more detail about your data object, it's hard to say exactly what you should do.  Here are some [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to consider.

Comment: define "arm package"

Comment: If your `n`'s were all 10 then you just need to divide those percentage values by 10 to get a count for a particular row to use as an x. If not, then its only a bit more complicated. It would be `n*percent/100`. You would not use anything for `prob`. It's not necessary if you have included the percentages in the x calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package:

```
install.packages("arm")
#------------
Installing package into ‘/home/david/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/arm_1.11-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 79464 bytes (77 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 77 KB

* installing *source* package ‘arm’ ...
** package ‘arm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (arm)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPzGMbH/downloaded_packages’
#---------------

 ?arm::discrete.histogram
```

You have redundant inforamtion so there are severa options.

a) Just use the Survival column for `x` as you have done.

b) If your n's were all 10 then you couldo divide those percentage values by 10 to get a count for a particular row to use as an x. If not, then its only a bit more complicated. It would be n*percent/100. You would not use anything for prob. It's not necessary if you have included the percentages in the x calculation.

c) Alternatively you could use the `n`'s as `x` and supply those percentages divided by 100 as a value for `prob`.